# Synchronous methods to connect documentdb

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, synchronous, azure-cosmosdb

Is there a way to connect, create, update, delete documents in DocumentDB by calling Synchronously using C#.NET?

Thanks,
Siva

Comment: Do you mean client.CreateDocumentAsync(..).Wait() or  client.CreateDocumentAsync().Result ?

Comment: I meant Synchronous methods not Asynchronous method like CreateDocumentAsync()

Comment: Putting a `wait` in front of an `...Async(...)` makes it read like synchronous code.

Comment: Yeah understood. But I'm writing a common code for all the DB calls like SQL, DocumentDB, SQLLite and so on. In DocumentDB most of the functions are Async type. So wanted to know is there any sync functions.

Comment: DocumentDB does not provide synchronous functions through the .NET client. Larry's suggestion is what is recommended i.e. use await